# Create Hibernate JPA Views

Tags: mysql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm looking to create a couple different views off from a primary table using a hibernate entity. I thought this would be a pretty standard scenario, however I haven't found much information on this topic.

The primary table will consist of locations and the view will be types of locations like state, country etc. I know this could be easily handled with a simple query restriction, however management would like to see it done using a view.

I'm wondering if the views could be created in hibernate JPA (using annotations).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Are you asking if you can have JPA entities mapped to database views?  You can do that, absolutely.

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely sure how it works, can the views be created in the database from the jpa, or do I need to create them in the database first then map the JPA entities to the database views?

Comment: I've never tried creating from JPA (using annotations).  I have used them after first creating in the database.

Answer (score 1):

if the schema looks like

```
id|locationtype|name|...
```

you could map your entities using TPH (Table per Hierarchy)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Location")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="locationtype", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
abstract class Location
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("state")
class State extends Location
{
    private String someOtherProp;
}
```

Comment: Could a restriction be added to your design? Example, only rows containing category "PEST", I'm trying to eliminate the need to use a composite key within my application, while also enabling the application to auto generate the tables as needed rather than manually running a sql statement.

Comment: in hibernate there is `<class where="sql"` don't know how to apply in JPA annotations. But columns in the where clause are not generated, they must be declared somewhere else too.